# LWJGL - Viewing loaded world

Tags: java, view, lwjgl

I am currently thinking of developing an MMORPG with a Java Client. It will be a survival sandbox game, with much wilderness.

Now I would like to know if there is any program which can get the loaded world out of the cache of the running client. (as image or something else visible) I need this because the world would be huge and it will help to hand out official maps for the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to start by looking into VBOs and VAOs (incredibly fast way of storing vertex, normal, texture... data on the GPU instead of the CPU). I'd also recommend checking out Blender, which I'm sure you've heard of, and their easily readable format known by the OBJ extension (The OBJ extension was developed by WaveFront). There are many libraries that allow you to read these files, but the format is simple enough that you can code an advanced mesh loader in around 80 lines or less.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question about whether or not you can get a world out of the cache, but if you're looking to get 3D data from an image, you can check out height maps. However, height maps are better for general terrain where you will NOT have caves. Generally things like that are loaded from a 3D modeling program's output.

This might go against what other people think, but the best way to start out is by using OpenGL to its potential. Of course this involves implementing your own matrix stack for shaders and so on, but the payoff of easy engine modifications in the end is great. The good thing about OpenGL is even though you might have Java or C++ or some language that you use, the methods remaing (generally) the same. However, the syntax does vary just like the languages do themselves.

Pyglet (Python bindings for OpenGL) is an interesting place to start if you are looking to get started with OpenGL while maintaining ease of programming and quick debugging (because it is an interpreted language) and dynamic typing helps because OpenGL can be picky about the types it accepts.

Comment: The OBJ format, was created by Wavefront Technologies and not Blender Foundation!

Comment: Yes I know, what I meant was Blender implemented the file format as an export option, but I didn't mean that they developed the format itself. Fixed for clarification though.